# Powershell Get-Process negative memory value

Tags: windows, powershell

I was making some verifications with Powershell Get-Process cmdlet and got some weird values about some processes. I tested on a server with a SQL Server Instance running and consuming 3GB+ RAM as Resource Monitor reported, and when running Get-Process, I got negative values for WorkingSet on the SQL server process, another process is consuming 2GB+ of PrivateMemorySize and got the same negative value on PM.

Below are screenshots of the results.

[image: Resource Monitor]
The OS is in portuguese, sorry.

Powershell:

[image]
Check sqlservr and the last scvhost...

Luckily my script uses WMI (Win32_Process class) to get the processes informations, and the values there are correct and everything matches..

Is it a bug? Maybe with big values? I'm using Powershell v3.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Is this an x64 Server? If so, it's possible [this blogpost](http://tfl09.blogspot.com/2008/12/get-process-produces-negative-numbers.html) explains your issue. Apparently it has to do with the way the get-process reads x64 systems memory:

> The reason the poster was seeing negative numbers is fairly simple: the WS property is aliased to WorkingSet, but WorkingSet is a 32-bit value. In the poster’s case, the working set size overflowed the 32-bit value, resulting in a negative number being displayed.

The solution according to the blog is ultimately to enforce formatting of the query result:

`$process = “*SQL"*” 
GPS $process | ft name, workingset64 –auto`

Comment: Thanks, I suspected it had something with values sizes and so on. Also, I can only get the correct results when running the command locally on the server, if I run remote with the -ComputerName parameter, I get the same negative results. Running with PSSession works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting WorkingSet64 instead of WorkingSet did the trick for me without formatting.